# Evernote Python API - Hitting rate limits

Tags: python, api, evernote

I've written a short piece of code that will append the tag names of my notes to the title, then remove all associated tags. When I try to run this on production, I hit the rate limit real quickly. Can someone help me optimise this piece of code? Or should I request for a special rate limit with Evernote?

Also, I get an error when a note has no tags. Any way to efficiently get the number of tags from a note so I don't get the error?

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.notestore import NoteStore

dev_token = "dev_token"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox = False)
userStore = client.get_user_store()
user = userStore.getUser()
print
print user.username
print

noteStore = client.get_note_store()
notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks()

for n in notebooks:
   print "Notebook = " + n.name + " GUID = " + n.guid

   filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
   filter.ascending = False
   filter.notebookGuid=n.guid

   spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
   spec.includeTitle = True
   spec.includeNotebookGuid = True
   spec.includeTagGuids = True

   notesMetadataList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 25, spec)
   for noteMetadata in notesMetadataList.notes:
      print "%s :: %s" % (noteMetadata.title, noteMetadata.guid)
      newNoteTitle = noteMetadata.title + " -- "
      for tagGuid in noteMetadata.tagGuids:
        tag = noteStore.getTag(tagGuid)
        tagName = tag.name
        print tagName
        newNoteTitle = newNoteTitle + " " + tagName
     print "newNoteTitle = " + newNoteTitle
     noteMetadata.title = newNoteTitle
     noteMetadata.tagGuids = []
     noteMetadata = noteStore.updateNote(noteMetadata)
     print noteMetadata.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I deal with rate limiting, by wrapping the `EvernoteClient` in a rate limiting proxy (based on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/)

```
from time import sleep
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.error.ttypes import (EDAMSystemException, EDAMErrorCode)


def evernote_wait_try_again(f):
    """
    Wait until mandated wait and try again
    http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/rate_limits.php
    """

    def f2(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except EDAMSystemException as e:
            if e.errorCode == EDAMErrorCode.RATE_LIMIT_REACHED:
                print("rate limit: {0} s. wait".format(e.rateLimitDuration))
                sleep(e.rateLimitDuration)
                print("wait over")
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return f2

class RateLimitingEvernoteProxy(object):
    __slots__ = ["_obj"]
    def __init__(self, obj):
        object.__setattr__(self, "_obj", obj)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return evernote_wait_try_again(
            getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj"), name))

_client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=sandbox)
client = RateLimitingEvernoteProxy(_client)
```

Comment: How is `evernote_wait_try_again` defined?

Comment: Fixed.  See https://github.com/rdhyee/evernote-web-utility/blob/0.0.6/EvernoteWebUtil/__init__.py#L55-L80 in context.